# Autofac equivalent of "BuildUp"

Tags: autofac

Structuremap defines a 'BuildUp' method that takes an already-constructed object and performs  setter injection to push in configured dependencies into that object.

Does Autofac have an equivalent method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was referring to already-constructed objects (ones not registered in the container) so the correct answer is either InjectProperties or InjectUnsetProperties.

The following test demonstrates the behaviour

```cs
    public class TestPropertyInjection
    {
        public object ShouldBeInjectedByAutofac { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Autofac_can_inject_properties()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(object));
        var container = builder.Build();

        var existingObjectNotRegisteredInContainer = new TestPropertyInjection();

        container.InjectProperties(existingObjectNotRegisteredInContainer);

        // can also use InjectUnsetProperties to only set unset properties
        //container.InjectUnsetProperties(existingObjectNotRegisteredInContainer);

       Assert.NotNull(existingObjectNotRegisteredInContainer.ShouldBeInjectedByAutofac);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [InjectUnsetProperties](http://api.autofac.org/html/3192DBAE.htm).
Sample:

```
public class YourModule : Module
{
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            builder.RegisterType<YourClass>().OnActivated(e => e.Context.InjectUnsetProperties(e.Instance));
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In more recent versions of Autofac you can simply use:

`builder.RegisterType<YourClass>().PropertiesAutowired();`

Comment: This works if Autofac *creates* YourClass, but it doesn't work at all if starting with a instanceOfYourClass.